# How can I tell if my dog wants to go outside to the toilet or to play?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, toilet-training, psychology

We've got a ~5 month old puppy, a Chihuahua/Yorkie crossbreed. She's just about completed toilet training now in the sense that she hasn't had an accident in the house for a while, but there's a problem in telling whether we're there or not: she begs to go outside constantly.

Most of the time, unless she's literally just been, we let her out. But most of the time she runs straight onto the lawn and grabs some bark chippings from the borders to chew or play chase. She's fast, small and agile so once she's in play mode, it can take a good few minutes of chasing to corner her and bring her inside again. At which point she'll beg to go out almost straight away.

She's very insistent about it too, scratching at the door glass and whining until someone does so. There's no difference in behaviour we can see between her asking to go out to the toilet and asking to go out to play. It's getting quite tiring and distracting: how can we tell or teach her the difference?